# How to avoid SetResult after task cancellation when using CancelAfter

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I converted an EAP into TAP. However, the event which is handled, may not be fired at all, which is why I add a timeout. See example code

```cs
class Request<T> {
    TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs;
    CancellationTokenSource cts;
    public int Timeout { get; }
    public bool IsCanceled => tcs.Task.IsCanceled;

    public Request(int timeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite) => Timeout = timeout;

    public Task<T> StartRequestAsync() {
        cts.Token.Register(() => tcs.SetCanceled());
        cts.CancelAfter(Timeout);
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    public void OnEvent(T result) {
        tcs.SetResult(result);
    }
}
```

Note that the `CancellationTokenSource` and `CancellationTokenRegistration` are both properly Disposed, in the implementation of `IDisposable` of the current class. The `StartRequestAsync` method is also thread-safely prevented from running more than once. The code is simplified for brevity.

Now, I'm externally setting the result of the task.

```cs
var req = new Request<int>();
if(!req.IsCanceled) 
{
    req.SetResult(5);
}
```

But I think there is a race condition. I assume the cancellation token `CancelAfter` works as an interrupt. If the token gets cancelled exactly after execution enters the `if` block, we could get `InvalidOperationException: An attempt was made to transition a task to a final state when it had already completed.`

Documentation states that TaskCompletionSource is thread-safe, so does that mean that `TrySetResult` is the atomic version of what I'm trying to achieve here? Is that what I should use instead?

Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Yes, TrySetResult is atomic and thread-safe, and will do what you want.

Comment: That said, you probably want TrySetCanceled as well, for the same reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to see how the [`SetResult`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TaskCompletionSource.cs.html#810e0ddcb0511ff1) and [`SetCanceled`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TaskCompletionSource.cs.html#32dd6288abd7ef1f) methods are implemented:

```
public void SetResult(TResult result)
{
    if (!TrySetResult(result))
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
            Environment.GetResourceString("TaskT_TransitionToFinal_AlreadyCompleted"));
}

public void SetCanceled()
{
    if(!TrySetCanceled())
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
            Environment.GetResourceString("TaskT_TransitionToFinal_AlreadyCompleted"));
}
```

As you can see, both methods delegate to their `Try` counterparts. You need them in order to detect errors in your code, in case your scenario is deterministic. If it's not, and race conditions are inherent in the scenario, just use the `Try` versions.